# Comparison string and array values

Tags: php, arrays, string

For e.g. we have string

```
$somestring = '11;11;11;12;13';
```

and array

```
    $somearray = array(
  11 => array(
    prop => array(0=>11),
    uid => 1,
  ),
  21 => array(
    prop => array(0=>12),
    uid => 2,
  ),
  32 => array(
    prop => array(0=>11),
    uid => 1,
  ),  
  34 => array(
    prop => array(0=>11),
    uid => 2,
  ),  
 35 => array(
    prop => array(0=>13),
    uid => 1,
  ),  
  36 => array(
    prop => array(0=>13),
    uid => 3,
  ),  
  37 => array(
    prop => array(0=>12),
    uid => 1,
  ),  
  38 => array(
    prop => array(0=>12),
    uid => 3,
  ),  
  39 => array(
    prop => array(0=>12),
    uid => 1,
  ),
);
```

How to get from $somearray [uid] on condition that value of [prop] is equal same value in  $somestring and output it by filled rows like this:

```
row1:11(uid:1);11(uid:1);11(uid:2);12(uid:2);13(uid:1)
row2:11(uid:);11(uid:);11(uid:);12(uid:1);13(uid:3)
row3:11(uid:);11(uid:);11(uid:);12(uid:3);13(uid:)
row4:11(uid:);11(uid:);11(uid:);12(uid:1);13(uid:)
```

I found a bit reletive solution here http://eval.in/6816 but it is not dealing with repeated values

Comment: Really, you should try it yourself. If you already have then [show us](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) .

Comment: I need direction. Should i firstly make from string array using explode or it is not nessesary?

Comment: row1:11(uid:1);11(uid:1);11(uid:2);12(uid:2);13(uid:1)                         what are 11,12,13 here? Are these keys from $somearray?

Comment: 11,12,13 are just come from $somestring , they are not keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy it and execute,

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$somestring = '11;11;11;12;13';

$somearray = array(
  11 => array(
    prop => array(0=>11),
    uid => 1,
  ),
  21 => array(
    prop => array(0=>12),
    uid => 2,
  ),
  32 => array(
    prop => array(0=>11),
    uid => 1,
  ),  
  34 => array(
    prop => array(0=>11),
    uid => 2,
  ),  
 35 => array(
    prop => array(0=>13),
    uid => 1,
  ),  
  36 => array(
    prop => array(0=>13),
    uid => 3,
  ),  
  37 => array(
    prop => array(0=>12),
    uid => 1,
  ),  
  38 => array(
    prop => array(0=>12),
    uid => 3,
  ),  
  39 => array(
    prop => array(0=>12),
    uid => 1,
  ),
);

$sme_array    = explode(";",$somestring);
$somestrarray = array_unique($sme_array);
$res          = array();
foreach($somearray as $key=>$val){

    foreach($somestrarray as $value){
        if($val['prop'][0] == $value){
           $res[$value][]   = $val['uid'];
        }       
    }
}

$cnt_values  = array_count_values($somestrarray);

$num_loop    = 1;
foreach($cnt_values as $key=>$val){
  $num_loop  = (count($res[$key])/$val) > $num_loop?(count($res[$key])/$val):$num_loop;
}

for($i=0; $i<$num_loop; $i++){
    echo "row".($i+1).":";
    foreach($sme_array as $vals){
      if(array_key_exists($vals,$res)){
      echo $vals."(uid:".$res[$vals][0].");";
      array_shift($res[$vals]);
      }
    }
    echo "<br>";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$str_array=explode(';',$somestring);
$final=array();

foreach($str_array as $key => $value1)
{
 foreach($somearray as $value2)
 {
  if($value2['prop'][0]==$value1)
  {
    $final[$key][]='row'.$key.':'.$value1.'(uid:'.$value2['prop'][0].')'; // something like this
  }
 }
}
   //print_r($final);

foreach($final as $keyy => $farr)
{
 $myarr[$keyy]=implode(';',$farr);
}

//print_r($myarr);
   echo implode('<br/>',$myarr);
```

Comment: @drupal2000 check the link and let me know any changes you need (http://eval.in/6795)

Comment: Thx, Harmeet, but this is not desired output . first row should be from example be row1:11(uid:1);11(uid:1);11(uid:2);12(uid:2);13(uid:1) , second row row2:11(uid:);11(uid:);11(uid:);12(uid:1);13(uid:3) and so on.

Comment: @drupal2000 ok check this http://eval.in/6802. Please let me know if the final array here is okay?

Comment: In your code first row lokks like row0:11(uid:11);row0:11(uid:11);row0:11(uid:11) this is not correct. First row should be row1:11(uid:1);11(uid:1);11(uid:2);12(uid:2);13(uid:1)

Comment: Every row should be '11;11;11;12;13' with correcponding by order uid values.

Comment: @drupal2000 ok. there has to be 5 rows.

Comment: Not 5 rows, how many row it depends how many the same values form string we meet in array [prop]. And every time new row are filled. So this is dynamic array.

Comment: @drupal2000 so I have say 7 values , what will be the rows like starting with row11...row13

Comment: Actaully in the post i show deaired output. If use data from my example rusult should be absolutely this one: row1:11(uid:1);11(uid:1);11(uid:2);12(uid:2);13(uid:1)
row2:11(uid:);11(uid:);11(uid:);12(uid:1);13(uid:3)
row3:11(uid:);11(uid:);11(uid:);12(uid:3);13(uid:)
row4:11(uid:);11(uid:);11(uid:);12(uid:1);13(uid:)